# Missing data column that doesn't

Tags: database, datatable

forgive me if i am asking silly question
but i can't figure it out what is wrong

In save button, i update datatables to database

```
        {
        new SqlCommandBuilder(sa);
        sa.Update(dtPurchaseProductExp);

        new SqlCommandBuilder(sa1);
        sa1.Update(dtPurchaseProduct);
        }
```

i don't have 'Unit' columns in dtPurchaseProductExp but
the following error shows up
[image]

[image: these are data columns of PurcaseProduct]

[image: these are data columns of PurcaseProductExp]

Comment: i see same error in
http://forums.asp.net/t/672823.

that suggest to use separate DataAdapter for each DataTable.

i use separate DataAdapter
but why the error shows up?
Someone HELP me!

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/672823.aspx